# PHP: How to compare keys in one array with values in another, and return matches?

Tags: php, arrays, compare, array-difference, array-intersect

I have the following two arrays:

```
$array_one = array('colorZero'=>'black', 'colorOne'=>'red', 'colorTwo'=>'green', 'colorThree'=>'blue', 'colorFour'=>'purple', 'colorFive'=>'golden');

$array_two = array('colorOne', 'colorTwo', 'colorThree');
```

**I want an array from `$array_one` which only contains the key-value pairs whose keys are members of $array_two** (either by making a new array or removing the rest of the elements from `$array_one`)

How can I do that?

I looked into `array_diff` and `array_intersect`, but they compare values with values, and not the values of one array with the keys of the other.

Comment: array_diff() or array_intersect() combined with [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

Check out the answer from Michel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30841097/2879722. It's a better and easier solution.

---

**Original Answer**

If I am understanding this correctly:

Returning a new array:

```
$array_new = [];
foreach($array_two as $key)
{
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array_one))
    {
        $array_new[$key] = $array_one[$key];
    }
}
```

Stripping from $array_one:

```
foreach($array_one as $key => $val)
{
    if(array_search($key, $array_two) === false)
    {
        unset($array_one[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What will be fast and less costly in terms of memory? I think the second one?

Comment: Yes, I would go for the second one. In it the smaller array is used for comparison and you are stripping an already set variable, not creating a new one.

Comment: Second approach is a Very good suggestion for quick "AND" comparison!

Answer (score 31):

As of PHP 5.1 there is `array_intersect_key` ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)).

Just flip the second array from *key=>value* to *value=>key* with `array_flip()` and then compare keys.

So to compare OP's arrays, this would do:

```
$result = array_intersect_key( $array_one , array_flip( $array_two ) );
```

No need for any looping the arrays at all.

Comment: Good one line solution, but I think this function loops the same.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if it works:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array_two);$i++){
  if($array_two[$i]==key($array_one)){
     $array_final[$array_two[$i]]=$array_one[$array_two[$i]];
     next($array_one);
  }
}
```

Comment: `$array_final` is a new array being created right? But I get `Notice: Undefined variable: array_final in C:\xampp\htdocs\testsNine.php on line 14` when I try to do `print_r($array_final);` after the loop. :s

Comment: sorry i forgot to declare it:
$array_final = array();

Comment: I did try to declare it. That prints a blank array. You had also confused `count($array_two)` with `$array_two.length` from JS. That had also produced an error. But I understand the concept. SO thank you.